# Error message did not show as I expected

Tags: c, printf, compression, stdout, stderr

For my following code, I expect to have an error message when the arguments are less than 3 while whether I typed in

```
./compress_uncompress -c compressedimg1 > image.bmp
```

or

```
./compress_uncompress -c compressedimg1
```

or

```
./compress_uncompress -c
```

I always get "couldn't open input file". Also, for

```
./compress_uncompress -e compressedimg1 > image.bmp
```

I expect to get error message of "invalid argv[1]" while I got it successfully decompressed without any error message.

```
unsigned long (*compressBound)(unsigned long length);
int (*compress)(void *dest, unsigned long* destLen, const void* source,       unsigned long sourceLen);
int (*uncompress)(void *dest, unsigned long* destLen, const void* source, unsigned long sourceLen);

void error_exit(const char *error_message)
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", error_message);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned long uncompressed_size;
    unsigned long compressed_size;
    char* uncompressed_buffer;
    char* compressed_buffer;
    int compress_result;
    int uncompress_result;

    void* lib = dlopen("libz.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if(lib == NULL)
    {
        error_exit("couldn’t open libz.so");
    }

    compressBound = dlsym(lib, "compressBound");
    if(compressBound == NULL)
    {
        error_exit("compress bound is null!");
    }

    compress = dlsym(lib, "compress");
    if(compress == NULL)
    {
        error_exit("couldn't load the compress symbol from zlib");
    }

    uncompress = dlsym(lib, "uncompress");
    if(uncompress == NULL)
    {
        error_exit("couldn't load the uncompress symbol from zlib");
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    if(fp == NULL){
        error_exit("couldn’t open input file");
    }

    if(argc < 3){
        error_exit("too few program arguments");
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"-c") == 0){
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); //to the end of the file
        uncompressed_size = ftell(fp); //find the size of the uncompressed file
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); //back to the begining
        uncompressed_buffer = malloc(uncompressed_size + 1);
        fread(uncompressed_buffer, uncompressed_size, 1, fp);
        compressed_size = compressBound(uncompressed_size);
        compressed_buffer = malloc(compressed_size);
        compress_result = compress(compressed_buffer, &compressed_size, uncompressed_buffer, uncompressed_size);
        if(compress_result < 0){
            error_exit("compress failed");
        }
        fwrite(&uncompressed_size, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, stdout);
        fwrite(&compressed_size, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, stdout);
        fwrite(compressed_buffer, compressed_size, 1, stdout);
    } else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-d") == 0){
        fread(&uncompressed_size, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, fp);
        fread(&compressed_size, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, fp);
        compressed_buffer = malloc(compressed_size);
        fread(compressed_buffer, compressed_size, 1, fp);
        uncompressed_buffer = malloc(uncompressed_size);
        uncompress_result = uncompress(uncompressed_buffer, &uncompressed_size, compressed_buffer, compressed_size);
        if(uncompress_result < 0){
            error_exit("uncompress failed");
        }
        fwrite(uncompressed_buffer, uncompressed_size, 1, stdout);
    } else{
        error_exit("invalid argv[1]");
    }
    free(uncompressed_buffer);
    free(compressed_buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're doing `fopen(argv[2], "rb")` before you check `if(argc < 3)`.

Comment: "./compress_uncompress -c image.bmp" I got a bunch of messy garbage and had to force quit... Do you know why's that?

Comment: You're writing binary data to the terminal, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I expect to compress .bmp and then decompress it to make sure the decompress and compress works correctly. checked by comparing the original file and the file after being compressed and decompressed.

Comment: But you're sending the compressed data to `stdout`. If you don't redirect the output, it goes to the terminal, and compressed data is not meaningful text.

Comment: It contains lots of control characters and escape sequences that can cause the terminal to do unpredictable things.

Comment: So the messy characters I saw in the terminal are just the compressed data?

Comment: Yes. You can experience this with `cat file.gz` where `file.gz` is an existing compressed file.

Comment: well, you add two options `-c` and `-d` and you call the third command with `-e` option, so it's normal you get there.